# Retrieving cut data in Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, cut

I'm searching for a way to get the data of the cut event in CKEditor. 
And i was looking within the sourcecode posted on github. 
But after trying to get the data on IE8, Mozilla(Mac) with the follow 2 examples

```
    editor.editable().on('cut', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.dataValue);
    });

    editor.editable().on('cut', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.data.dataValue);
    });
```

I couldn't find out what is the problem for not retrieving the data.
Does somebody know how to retrieve the data from the cut event in CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

CKEditor utilizes native `document.execCommand` for clipboard operations. It doesn't store what is cut/copied but the browser does. All browsers except IE won't let you manipulate clipboard data (IE will display a prompt first). In fact, CKEditor has (almost) nothing to do with cutting process.

In IE and Webkit, you can try [onbeforecut](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkadrvv.php) event to listen on and access editor's selection with `editor.getSelection()` (i.e. `editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()`).

Comment: I did already find the editor.getSelection().getSelectedText(); indeed. But it seemed curious that the dataValue wasn't filled.

Comment: dataValue isn't filled because CKEditor *never* handles cutting process. The browser is responsible for controlling the clipboard. It's totally native.